# Populate Email with Smart Capture Form Submissions

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to automate email sends to the respective reps depending on form submissions. I'm building the emails and can't figure a way of populating the form content into the email. The goal is to send each form submission to the proper Rep with the form details. Any insight?

Answer (score 2):

If the Smart Capture block's Data Target points to a data extension (e.g., CloudPages_DataExtension or some other), you can leverage the AMPscript Data Extension functions in the email to retrieve the captured values based on a common attribute (e.g., EmailAddress). You can find some examples in the documentation:

- [Function Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm)
- [AMPscript 201](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript201.htm) (Lookup)
- [AMPscript 301](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript301.htm) (LookupRows)

I suppose you could also consider [triggered send data extensions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_create_triggered_send_data_extension.htm&type=5). With [triggered sends](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_triggered_sends.htm&type=5), you'd be able to use substituion strings instead of AMPscript lookups.